# Sync a fork with original: Problems with merge and rebase

Tags: android, git, github

I'm working in android development, so I decided to upload my own changes of a team's rom to my github.

I did a fork of some projects like framework/base, so I have my own commits there. The problem comes when I set as remote the original github project, using this guide [enter link description here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/):

I want to have a clean history, so if the original project add 4 commits, I want to have them in the top of my github, one by one. If I use git rebase in my personal branch, then my history will be rewritten, and on the other hand, if I use git merge, then I will only have 1 commit with all the changes.

So is there a way, appart of cherry-picking every change manually, to add the new commits one by one of the original team's project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A merge by default should get you the n new commits +1 merge commit. Not only a merge commit alone.

Comment: But this is only when the merge have any conflicts, if not, it only appears "merge....branch..into...".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you may be able to get what you want by rebasing the original project on your personal branch, and then pushing the result to your remote personal branch.

Let's assume that the original project and your personal branch have each diverged by two commits:

```
original: A <- B <- C <- D
personal: A <- B <- E <- F
```

Checkout the latest **original** branch, pull it, and then rebase it on your **personal** branch:

```
git checkout original
git pull origin original
git rebase personal
```

After you have resolved every merge conflict in the rebase, your local original branch will look like the following:

`original: A <- B <- E <- F <-``C'``<- D'`

I have labelled the commits C and D above with primes because they are new commits made on a codebase different than the original C and D commits.

The final step will be to push your result to the **personal** repository.  You should be able to just fast-forward your remote **personal** repo:

```
git push origin original:personal
```

This would seem to give you what you want.  You now have the changes from original in your personal branch without rewriting your history.  Please let me know if I misunderstanding your question.

Comment: The problem is that it changes my local and online history, because as you say it will add C' and D', but it will move my commits E and F to the top, so in github the order is now different (A B C' D' and then my new commits E F).

Comment: EDIT: What I don't want to change is the order of the commits of my gihub, like the example you have over here. But thinking about it, if I do git pull in the original branch and then I do git rebase personal, if after that in my personal branch I do git rebase original, it should work right?. In the case the answer is yes, what is better to use when I'm in my personal branch (after git pull in original and git rebase personal) git rebase or git merge?

Comment: To your second comment, you should not have to rebase personal on original because you can simply fast-forward personal with the original branch from my example above.  Could you give a better example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: But if the commits of the source change some of mines, then I can't do fast-forward. And if I solve the conflicts and do git rebase in my personal branch the my commits log changes, because git, to keep my commits,  put first the commits I rebased, and then it puts my commits (the ones that were changed becouse of the original commits). What I want is not to change my commits log. I'm not sure if my explanation is well